# Why does this Makefile fail to build make the final target, but all intermediate targets work fine?

Tags: makefile, runtime-error

Say we have the following Makefile:

```
.PHONY: build
build:
    cd .. && make

%.hl.a.json: %.c
    touch $@

%.hl.b.json: %.hl.a.json
    touch $@

%.x.p.json: %.hl.b.json
    touch $@

%.x.hl.a.json: %.x.p.json
    touch $@

%.x.hl.b.json: %.x.hl.a.json
    touch $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) *.json
```

Let us assume we have file called `small.c`, and that I want to build `small.hl.b.json`. However, running `make small.hl.b.json` (with GNU Make 3.81) gives me:

```
$ make small.x.hl.b.json
make: *** No rule to make target `small.x.hl.b.json'.  Stop.
```

However, the Makefile works for building `small.x.hl.a.json` which produces

```
$ make small.x.hl.a.json
touch small.hl.a.json
touch small.hl.b.json
touch small.x.p.json
touch small.x.hl.a.json
rm small.x.p.json small.hl.a.json small.hl.b.json
```

Thus, if I run `make small.x.hl.a.json` first, and *then* `make small.x.hl.b.json`, then everything works.

And now it gets interesting. If I do the following:

```
$ make small.x.hl.a.json
touch small.hl.a.json
touch small.hl.b.json
touch small.x.p.json
touch small.x.hl.a.json
rm small.x.p.json small.hl.a.json small.hl.b.json

$ make clean
rm -f *.json

$ make small.x.hl.b.json
make: *** No rule to make target `small.x.hl.b.json'.  Stop.
```

it does not work. But it *does* work if I do this:

```
$ make small.x.hl.a.json
touch small.hl.a.json
touch small.hl.b.json
touch small.x.p.json
touch small.x.hl.a.json
rm small.x.p.json small.hl.a.json small.hl.b.json

$ make clean small.x.hl.b.json
rm -f *.json
touch small.hl.a.json
touch small.hl.b.json
touch small.x.p.json
touch small.x.hl.a.json
touch small.x.hl.b.json
rm small.x.p.json small.hl.a.json small.hl.b.json
```

Can someone tell me what's going on? And why can't I build `small.x.hl.b.json` directly but instead must first build `small.x.hl.a.json` and *then* `small.x.hl.b.json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a tutorial saying that:

> The rule with the shorted stem will be tried first, and if there is a tie the rule that appears first will be selected.

So I tried swapping the order of the rules so that .x. targets appear first, and then everything works!

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, and I'll delete this answer if anyone can provide a better one, but **this looks to me like a bug in GNUMake 3.81**:

Make first considers the target `small.x.hl.b.json`, and finds two pattern rules that match it:

```
%.hl.b.json: %.hl.a.json # call this rule 2
    ...

%.x.hl.b.json: %.x.hl.a.json # call this rule 5
    ...
```

Note that both of these rules have *the same prerequisite,* namely `small.x.hl.a.json`.

It looks as if Make then makes a mistake. (Here's where I go out on a limb.) It goes searching for a way to build `small.x.hl.a.json`, remembering that it has already used rules 2 and 5, *but failing to remember that they are parallel alternatives, not sequential steps.* Later on, when Make needs `small.hl.b.json`, the only rule that will serve is rule 2, which Make rejects on the grounds that it must not use the same pattern rule twice in a chain. Never mind that this invocation would use a shorter stem, never mind that the chain in question is actually two chains, one of which has not yet used Rule 2, Make considers this a dead end.

This fits the results of the other experiments as well. Make can build `small.x.hl.b.json` without this self-collision, and once that target is built, Make can then build `small.x.hl.b.json` in a single step without a troublesome chain.